# How to get the instance of UINavigationController in react native [iOS]

Tags: react-native

I need to implement a function like this in my native siwft code:

```swift
public func onThreeDSChallengeRequired(completion: @escaping (UINavigationController) -> Void) {
    completion(self.viewController)
}
```

I am using `expo` with a development client not Expo Go, and [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) is installed in the project.

How to get the correct instance of UINavigationController? can I just create a new one, or should I get the existing one from other library like `React/RCTUtils.h`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your own instance of `UINavigationController` and push it to the current `UIViewController` provided by react native utility method `RCTPresentedViewController`:

```swift
internal class OppwaHandler: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, OPPThreeDSEventListener {
    let viewController = RCTPresentedViewController()  // step 1: get the current `UIViewController`

    public func onThreeDSChallengeRequired(completion: @escaping (UINavigationController) -> Void) {
        if let rootViewController = self.viewController {
            let nc = UINavigationController()  // step 2 create your own instance of UINavigationController
            nc.delegate = self  // not sure if this is required, but my class inherited from UINavigationControllerDelegate, so this line is at least valid
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                rootViewController.present(nc, animated: true) {
                    completion(nc)
                }
            }
        }
```